# How do I show that a reduced density matrix of $1$ is $\rho_{12}^{1} = Tr_{2}[\rho_{12}] = \sum_{i}\langle i_{2} | \rho | i_{2} \rangle$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, linear-algebra

Let the system be a 2 - qubit system and let $\rho_{12}$ be a density matrix of some state for this 2 - qubit system.

> How do I show that a reduced density matrix of $1$ is $\rho_{12}^{1} = Tr_{2}[\rho_{12}] = \sum_{i}\langle i_{2} | \rho | i_{2} \rangle$?

My workings:

$\rho_{12} = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi |_{12} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}|i\rangle\langle i|_{12} = |1_{1}1_{2}\rangle\langle 1_{1}1_{2}| + ...$

Then: $\rho_{12}^{1} = Tr_{2}[\rho_{12}] = \sum_{i=1}^{N}|i_{1}\rangle \langle i_{1}|Tr[|i_{2}\rangle \langle i_{2}|] = \sum_{i=1}^{N}|i_{1}\rangle \langle i_{1}| \langle i_{2} | i_{2} \rangle] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} |i_{1}\rangle \langle i_{1}|$

I suspect I'm stuck due to a lack of familiarity with a more abstract form.

Comment: What exactly do you want to show?  $\sum_i \langle i_2| \rho | i_2 \rangle$ is the definition of the partial trace. That's how we define what partial trace is.